# Deleting all rvalue function overloads of a class

Tags: c++, overloading, delete-operator, rvalue

Say I have a class object that *must* be captured by the caller when returning this class's object from a function call.

```cpp
// no_can_rvalue *must* be captured
[[nodiscard]] no_can_rvalue a_func();
```

I can enforce this by deleting all rvalue function overloads, thus making it impossible to use the class functionality unless a caller has captured an object of it (doubled with `nodiscard` in c++17).

Is it possible to delete *all* rvalue function overloads of a given class in one fell swoop?

The result being equivalent to :

```cpp
struct no_can_rvalue {
    void f() && = delete;
    void f() &;
    void g() && = delete;
    void g() &;
    // etc
};
```

Comment: Note that you only need `&& = delete` for `const` functions. For non-const functions, adding `&` on the primary overload is enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ty I had no idea!

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: @JeffGarrett You must capture the thing, because it returns iterators that point to itself. aka, you cannot `for (auto v : m.get_no_can_rvalue())`. Which is also a perf concern in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do so.